# passing value from textbox to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I get value from textbox "EmailList" and send it to controler? I'm always using webforms, and this is my first contact with mvc.

View:

```
    @Html.TextBox("EmailList")
    @Html.Action("SendEmails")
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult SendEmails()
    {

        // some operations on EmailList
    }
```

EDIT


And what if I need just to open simple method 'onclick'? Not actionresult. for example -

```
       public void SendEmails()
        {
            // some operations on EmailList
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to get the value back into the controller you're going to need to issue a `POST` first of all so you'll want to setup your controller action for a `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmails(string EmailList)
{
}
```

also notice I added a parameter `EmailList` that's named exactly the same as the control on the form. Next we need to make sure your HTML is setup right, so when you build the `form` control build it like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm("SendEmails", "{ControllerNameHere}", FormMethod.Post)
```

and then your text box, well leave it alone, it should work just fine.

Comment: And please tell me, how to prevent this form from "f5" button or reload page?

Comment: @whoah, you want to stop the user from being able to reload the page? Are you saying during the submit? Or are you saying completely?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the `EmailList` to a method then you should have a form surrounding with the email textfield

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("",""))
{
    @Html.TextBox("EmailList")
    <input type="submit" id="emailSubmit" value="Submit Email" />
}
```

Then write a script to override the form default behaviour

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var emailValue = $("#EmailList").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SendEmails',
                data: { text: emailValue }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now you can add a parameter to your method like this:

```
public void SendEmails(string text)
        {
            string email=text;
            //or you can look into the Request.Form or Request.Querystring 
        }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Have a model

```
public class EmailSubmitModel
{
    public string EmailList {get; set;}
}
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult SendEmails(EmailSubmitModel emailSubmitModel)
{


}
```