# how to have HTML.BeginForm only reload the partial view in which it is contained

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view which lists a table of items. I want this table to be searchable there will be a lot of items to display or look through. I was using HTML.BeginForm but have found that it doesn't work. 
Here is the code:
OrderController:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ItemListPartialView(string searchString) {
    var items = _itemControls.GetAllItems()
        .Select(x => new ItemOrderViewModel() {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Price = Convert.ToString(x.Price, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Size = x.Size + " " + x.QuantityType.Name,
            Quantity = 0
        });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
        items = items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
    }

    return PartialView("_ItemListPartialView", items);
}
```

And Views:

Main View:

```
<pre>Index</pre>

<pre>
    @Html.Action("ItemListPartialView", "Order")
</pre>
```

PartialView:

```
<pre>@model IEnumerable<CyreniansFarm.Display.ViewModels.ItemOrderViewModel>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/AddItemToList.js")

@using (Html.BeginForm("ItemListPartialView", "Order"))
{
    <p>Find by name: @Html.TextBox("searchString") <pre>Submit button</pre>
}</pre>

<pre>
    <preid="itemsTable" class="table">
        <pre>
            <pre></pre>
            <pre>Name</pre>
            <pre>Price</pre>
            <pre>Size</pre>
            <pre>Quantity</pre>
            <pre></pre>
        </pre>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <pre>
                <pre>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)</pre>
                <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</pre>
                <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</pre>
                <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size)</pre>
                <pre>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = 0 } })</pre>
            </pre>
            }
    </pre>
</pre>
```

Sorry about formatting first time posting code in stackoverflow.
But yeah I want the BeginForm to just submit to the method within the controller that the partial view comes from not the whole actual page itself. Is there a way to do this?
Or is there a way using JS/AJAX or JQuery in which to take the input from the tet box and search and display the related info?
I'm pretty new to the JS stuff so have no idea how I would go about doing this. Thanks

Comment: I changed everything to the pre tags cause i misread the HTML rules....sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to see if it works.
References: [passing value from textbox to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422311/passing-value-from-textbox-to-controller)

Step 1: Try replacing codes in **PartialView** with:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ItemListPartialView", "Order"))
{
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
    <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />
}
```

Step 2: Try amending codes in **OrderController** with:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemListPartialView(string searchString) {
    var items = _itemControls.GetAllItems()
        .Select(x => new ItemOrderViewModel() {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Price = Convert.ToString(x.Price, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Size = x.Size + " " + x.QuantityType.Name,
            Quantity = 0
        });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
        items = items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
    }

    return PartialView("_ItemListPartialView", items);
}
```